# How to make infinite buffer on ns 2?

Tags: networking, buffer, ns2

Does anyone know how to make infinite buffer on NS 2 simulator?

I have been tried to make buffer(queue-limit) as big as possible but still i have lost packet while running the simulation.

Comment: Hints https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+infinite+buffer .... Besides that : Please edit your question to include the protocol used. ... And probably also add your "simulation.tcl". .... How do you measure "packets dropped" ? Which script ? ... All ~240 scripts : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rU_MFAEl1GCLMTJPLR3zbxPxkQQHkQ7T?usp=sharing

Comment: thankyou for reply, i add my tcl on my new post please check it thankyou sir.

Comment: thankyou for reply, i add my tcl on my new post please check it thankyou sir @KnudLarsen